# How to check if a rowNode is in the search result [Aggird]

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

A quick question about ag-grid. When looping through forEachNode function, how can I tell if a rowNode exists in the grid search result (i.e. visible)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the api call forEachNodeAfterFilter:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#gsc.tab=0

> **forEachNodeAfterFilter(callback)**
>   Similar to forEachNode, except skips any filtered out data.

```
gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter = function(params) {
     // access to visible node
     params.node
}
```